# Angular 2 and Angular Cli tree shaking production build, vendor.js huge

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have done a small Angular 4 app, but I do not know how to apply tree shaking and aot compiling. 
the command I run is the following:

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

But the result I get is still huge, vendor file is 2.63Mb:

```
Hash: 3f2f9863802ffee21a18
Time: 35397ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.3be44b11f98572593d31.bundle.js (polyfills) 158 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.62b1e2f835ae0e344351.bundle.js (main) 537 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.6ad044d12ab50a9da898.bundle.css (styles) 69 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.a13d6c29b7348e1ae91d.bundle.js (vendor) 2.63 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.01f2c419c67f5155d8a3.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
```

**Is this the final application, or something is wrong with ng cli?**

This is my version of the CLI:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.4
node: 6.10.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.0.0-rc.6
@angular/compiler: 4.0.0-rc.6
@angular/core: 4.0.0-rc.6
@angular/forms: 4.0.0-rc.6
@angular/http: 4.0.0-rc.6
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.2
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.0-rc.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.0-rc.6
@angular/router: 4.0.0-rc.6
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.0-rc.6
```

Comment: Maybe this is a bug? I updated a small angular 2 app to angular 4 today, and the vendor.js file increased from 380KB to 1.3MB, and the scripts.js file from 95.3KB to 545KB.

Comment: I thought as of the last version the AOT was automatically the default for `ng`. I may be wrong though. I use `ngc` myself to control what gets deployed and my entire site (angular 2 stuff + with a few third party libraries, bootstrap, my own CSS files and maybe around 30 components) is ~350kb zipped.

Comment: Use `source-map-explorer`.

Answer (score 6):

Angular 4 prod build with tree shake and aot can be acheived by just running `ng build --prod` --aot flag not required now.

Build should look like this ( chunk    {5} vendor.46351c4e9fc678f82bca.bundle.js (vendor) 1.13 MB [initial] [rendered] )

Note: in this output 1.13MB is not what you get, look your file size in /dist directory what you get is 316KB )

[build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0ext.png)

[what we get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTwpv.png)

Comment: Just to add on to this, this was a bug in the CLI (showing the wrong file sizes in the build output) that has been fixed since versions `1.3.x`.